# White Background showing as Grey when exporting from indesign to PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf

I have an image in Photoshop that is on a white background. I've imported it into Indesign and added type. When exporting it as a PDF to send on to my client, the white background is showing as a light grey. If I open the PDF in photoshop it shows as white and if I output to preview it shows as white, however it also printing out as grey.

I'm using CoatedFogra39 (ISO 12647-2: 2004) but have tried Fogra27, I have tried RGB and CMYK with little difference. I'm on the creative cloud so all is up to date. I have sent both versions to the client and they appear fine on their screen so fairly certain it's a settings thing.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Your question might be answerable, but there's some missing information.  Can you please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/130671/edit) and supply the following information:  Is the image CMYK or RGB?  What colour profiles are you using? What software are you or your client using to view/print the PDF?

Comment: I'm using CoatedFogra39 (ISO 12647-2: 2004) but have tried Fogra27, I have tried RGB and CMYK with little difference. I'm on the creative cloud so all is up to date. I have sent both versions to the client and they appear fine on their screen so fairly certain it's a settings thing.

Comment: I've added the information to your question. You can delete the comment above now.  I'm not sure if this can really be answered without access to the file itself. It's hard to come up with anything but guesses - for example: could it be a problem with your printer/print settings?

Comment: Is it *really* "white"? If you open n Photoshop and move the cursor over the "white" area -- watching the **Info Panel** -- do all the color values stay at 0 (CMYK) or 255 (RGB)? A "scum dot" (1-3% of a color) may be more visible in a PDF than it is is Photoshop itself.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem. After a lot of experimenting I found that it was caused by the image being rotated (in Indesign). When I straightened the image the background turned to pure white again. I just rotated the images in photoshop instead. I hope this helps.